# Change Permissions for SSH User

Tags: ssh, permissions, user-accounts, synology

In my Synology NAS, I have created a SSH user whose home directory is `/volume1/USERNAME`. However, this user can access other directories.

Is there a way to limit him to not be able to access anything outside of his home directory?

Comment: if synology is using openssh, then you can define `ChrootDirectory`

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

So, setting up chroot for SSH requires enabling SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol), which is a part of OpenSSH.    Read below for exact steps.

BTW if you see USERNAME in all caps, replace USERNAME with the username you are trying to chroot.

**Enabling Chrooted SFTP**

Enabling SFTP is very easy. Open /etc/ssh/sshd_config...

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and make sure you have the following line in it:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Then add the following stanza at the end of the file (add such a stanza for each user that you want to chroot):

```
Match User USERNAME
    ChrootDirectory /home
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Instead of adding a stanza for each user, you can also chroot groups, e.g. as follows:

```
Match Group users
    ChrootDirectory /home
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

This would chroot all members of the users group to the /home directory.
Restart OpenSSH:

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

If you chroot multiple users to the same directory, but don't want the users to browse the home directories of the other users, you can change the permissions of each home directory as follows:

```
chmod 700 /home/USERNAME
```

Afterwards, you can log in with an SFTP client, such as FileZilla or WinSCP.

**Enabling Chrooted SSH**

Enabling chrooted SSH is a bit more complicated because we must set up a chroot environment with all programs/tools (e.g. /bin/bash, /bin/cp, etc.) that the users should be able to use. This means we must also copy all libraries that these programs need to the chroot jail. You can do this manually with the cp command, and you can find out what libraries a tool needs by using the ldd command, e.g.

```
ldd /bin/bash
```

We also have to create some devices such as /dev/null, /dev/zero, /dev/tty, and /dev/urandom inside the chroot jail with the mknod command.
However, this can be a tedious task. Fortunately, there's a script that can do this for us.
First, we need to install some prerequisites:

```
apt-get install sudo debianutils coreutils
```

Then we download make_chroot_jail.sh to /usr/local/sbin and make it executable for the root user:

```
cd /usr/local/sbin
wget http://www.fuschlberger.net/programs/ssh-scp-sftp-chroot-jail/make_chroot_jail.sh
chmod 700 /usr/local/sbin/make_chroot_jail.sh
```

Before we use the script, you might want to add some programs (e.g. such as /usr/bin/vi) to the APPS line of your distribution in that script so that these tools get added to the chroot jail automatically:

```
vi /usr/local/sbin/make_chroot_jail.sh


elif [ "$DISTRO" = DEBIAN ]; then
  APPS="/bin/bash /bin/cp /usr/bin/dircolors /bin/ls /bin/mkdir /bin/mv /bin/rm /bin/rmdir /bin/sh /bin/su /usr/bin/groups /usr/bin/id /usr/bin/rsync /usr/bin/ssh /usr/bin/scp /sbin/unix_chkpwd /usr/bin/vi"
else
```

Next we add a symlink /home/home that points back to /home:

```
cd /home
ln -s . home
```

Now we can already use the script. Usage is as follows:

```
make_chroot_jail.sh username [/path/to/chroot-shell [/path/to/chroot]]
```

chroot-shell is a special shell created by the script to chroot users. Since OpenSSH now supports chrooting by default, we don't need the script to create a special shell; instead, we can use /bin/bash or /bin/sh.
It doesn't matter if the user is already existing or not. If he's existing, he will be updated; if not, he will be created.

```
make_chroot_jail.sh USERNAME /bin/bash /home
```

This will create/update the user USERNAME with the chroot jail /home.
To update all files/libraries in the chroot jail, run

```
make_chroot_jail.sh update /bin/bash /home
```

Now we need to configure OpenSSH which is similar to the SFTP configuration. Open /etc/ssh/sshd_config...

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

And add the following stanza at the end of the file (add such a stanza for each user that you want to chroot):

```
Match User USERNAME
    ChrootDirectory /home
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

Instead of adding a stanza for each user, you can also chroot groups, e.g. as follows:

```
Match Group users
    ChrootDirectory /home
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

This would chroot all members of the users group to the /home directory.
The difference to the SFTP configuration is that this time, we must not use the line ForceCommand /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server in the Match stanzas! This makes that users can still use chrooted SFTP (provided you also have the line Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server in /etc/ssh/sshd_config), but also chrooted SSH.

Restart OpenSSH

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

If you chroot multiple users to the same directory, but don't want the users to browse the home directories of the other users, you can change the permissions of each home directory as follows:

```
chmod 700 /home/USERNAME
```

Afterwards, you can log in with with an SSH client such as PuTTY.